# Incrementing integer with multiple sources of input C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game there is a score. When an object collides, a set increment is added to the score. There is one scoreboard. What is happening in my game is that when an object collides it hijacks the scoreboard to show only its own person history of scores. When the next object collides, it takes over the scoreboard and shows its own personal history. I am trying to show the amalgamate score of all of the objects put together, each contributing their part to a grand total.

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "Plane")
    {
        score += 50;
        textMeshComponent = GameObject.Find ("Score").GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
        textMeshComponent.text = score.ToString ();

    }
}
```

There are 10 of (col.gameObject.name) and there is one "Plane" that they all interact with.

How can I make the score a conglomerate like I described? I am really at a loss for how to manipulate the (col.gameObject.name) side of that equation.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Best guess is that score is a member of the gameObject (hence each object maintains it's own score).  Make score a member of Plane, and make it accessible to the gameObjects.

Comment: Score is actually 3D text so it is its own independent GameObject

Comment: This score: `GameObject.Find ("Score")` is it's own object, but this score: `score += 50;` seems to belong to the individual game objects.

Comment: make GameObject a singleton.

Comment: Ian you were right. Thanks. You are el genius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `score` a member of `Plane`, instead of `this`, and make it `public` so all the other gameObjects can get it.

You can also create score as its own gameObject, or create a gameObject that contains all the globals.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another approach although not recommended textMeshComponent.text = (score+(int.Parse(textMeshComponent.text))).toString();
now this will add points as a whole regardless each gameobject adding  its own to the main value

Answer (score 0):

Consider having an object in your scene whose sole concern is counting (and maybe displaying) the score. Lets name it ScoreController.

Whenever an event occurs for which you want to award score to the player, the responsible code just calls your ScoreController and tells them how much score to award.

Your ScoreController GameObject might have a script like this:

```
public class ScoreController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMesh scoreDisplay;

    public int Score { get; private set; }

    void Start()
    {
        UpdateView();
    }

    public void AwardScore(int amount)
    {
        Score += amount;
        UpdateView();
    }

    private void UpdateView()
    {
        scoreDisplay.text = Score.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, other code can award score by calling

```
GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ScoreController>().AwardScore(123);
```

If you want to read up on related topics, consider reading about the Model-View-Control design pattern, and about SoC (seperation of concerns).